# Is there a way to get the user-preference Time Zone value from the Dwolla API?

Tags: api, timezone, dwolla

The Dwolla transaction "Date" field apparently uses this value for generating a timestamp, but I don't see any way to get the "Time Zone" preference from the API?

Zooming out, I'm trying to get the definitive/comparable date for a transaction, but I need to know the timezone of the date string.

Answer (score 0):

While [this method](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/transactions/byid) doesn't state what the time zone is, others like [this one](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/transactions/listing) make it clear that the dates are in UTC, so I would guess that all dates are in UTC throughout the API.

The only thing I don't like about their API is they are showing example dates like:

```json
"Date": "8/31/2011 10:19:09 AM"
```

It's not very smart of them to use M/D/YYYY format, nor to use a 12-hour clock.  This is better represented by `"2011-08-31T10:19:09Z"`, which is in ISO format and indicates UTC.  If you ever get a chance to speak with them, you should recommend they use this format (ISO-8601).

Just be aware of this when you are parsing it, since the format they are using may or may not be the correct format for your current culture.

Comment: I assumed this too, and it makes sense to me, but this is not how the Dwolla API is performing. If I set my Time Zone to California I get "12/03/2013 13:34:56", but if I change (in the "Account Info" of Dwolla settings) my Time Zone to Hawaii, then for the exact same transaction the Date comes back as "12/03/2013 11:34:56"

Comment: So, in your tests, the results do not come back as UTC?

Comment: Exactly. The Date field of the transaction is coming back in local time (24hr format), but I don't see any way to get the local time zone.

Comment: Hmmm.... what language are you calling the api from?  Can you show the code you are using to make the call and parse the results?  It's entirely possible they are coming back as UTC but then getting translated to your server's local time zone.  This could happen easily with .NET and the `DateTime` type, but I'm not sure if that's what you're using or something else.

Comment: I'm using the Python library recommended by Dwolla (https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/samples/python) and it doesn't look like it's doing any date translation, or even parsing => https://github.com/Dwolla/dwolla-python/blob/master/dwolla/__init__.py

Comment: I just tried it from Dwolla's developer page with the "Try method now" button and it returns a JSON tree with the same local date string and no timezone info... so I don't think it's a client library issue.

Comment: I work at Dwolla.  Kevin is correct that this is an issue of our API returning timestamps in the local time set by each user but not indicating what that timezone is.  We will fix this by returning UTC, but we are currently working out how to make this change without breaking existing implementations.  This means we may introduce a new date parameter like "DateUTC".  Stay tuned to our developer mailing list for our decision in the coming week.

Comment: @Gordon - please be sure to return it in ISO8601 format with a trailing Z to indicate UTC.

Comment: Thanks @GordonZheng! I just joined the developer mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Dwolla  are making the change to the ISO timestamp on August 4th 2014

This change will be rolled out in 60 days from today, on 9:00 AM CT August 4th, 2014. If you need help making adjustments to your code to parse the new datetime format, let us know and we'll be glad to lend a hand.

https://discuss.dwolla.com/t/api-update-new-timestamp-format-for-clearingdate-parameter/401